# Creating an animated gif from a CSS3 animated SVG

Tags: css, animation, svg, gif, animated-gif

I have a question - wondering whether it's possible to create an animated GIF from an existing animation which is made up of SVGs animated using CSS3 transitions?

The existing SVG is basically a pie chart made up of 4 parts that grow out from the centre by putting on a transition of width .2s height .2s on each piece. I've made a JSBin of it here:

http://jsbin.com/UcemUNo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

I've had a look around & all I can find is how to just 'create an animated gif' through say a webcam or existing images, but not from an element on a web page.

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution - screen recording! Downloaded a program called Camtastia, recorded the animation in my browser & exported it as an animated GIF. Job done.